# Send input to command line prompt from Python program

Tags: python, starcluster

I believe this to be a very simple question, but I have been failing to find a simple answer.

I am running a python program that terminates an AWS cluster (using starcluster).  I am just calling a command from my python program using subprocess, something like the following.

```
subprocess.call('starcluster terminate cluster', shell=True)
```

The actual command is largely irrelevant for my question but provides some context.  This command will begin terminating the cluster, but will prompt for a yes/no input before continuing, like so:

```
Terminate EBS cluster (y/n)?
```

How do I automate typing yes from within my python program as input to this prompt?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12982539

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can write to stdin using Popen:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
proc = Popen(['starcluster', 'terminate', 'cluster'], stdin=PIPE)
proc.stdin.write("y\r")
```

Answer (score 9):

While [possible to do with `subprocess` alone in somewhat limited way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12980148/using-pythons-subprocess-and-popen-in-one-script-to-run-another-python-script-w/12982539#12982539), I would go with [`pexpect`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for such interaction, e.g.:

```
import pexpect
child = pexpect.spawn('starcluster terminate cluster')
child.expect('Terminate EBS cluster (y/n)?')
child.sendline('y')
```

Comment: who said it first? :) well, I deleted my answer it was less detailed than yours

Comment: @mguijarr That's why it took longer to write :) Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

It might be simplest to check the documentation on the target program. Often a flag can be set to answer yes to all prompts, e.g., `apt-get -y install`.